# taking function as an input in SageMath

Tags: sage

How do you make a function that takes a function as input?
What I want to do is something like:

```
f(x) = log(x)
g(f, x) = x^2 * f(x)

g(f, 2) 
# Symbolic expression of x^2 * log(x)
```

I think I am looking for the way to create higher order function.

Answer (score 3):

Would using a lambda function for `g` work for you?

Here is a way to do that:

```py
sage: f(x) = log(x)
sage: g = lambda u, v: v*2 * u(v)
sage: g(f, 2)
4*log(2)
```

Comment: I haven't noticed. This also works if we call it like `g(f,x)`. Much cleaner than my attempt!

Answer (score 2):

We can create a python function that returns a symbolic function and takes two symbolic functions as an input.

Consider the following code.

```py
g(x) = x^2
f(x) = log(x)

def foo(f, g, x):
    return g(x) * f(x)

z(x)=foo(g, f, x)
```

Take a look at it.

```py
sage: z
```

which yields to the symbolic function

```py
x |--> x^2*log(x)
```